# Access currently loaded store from external js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I cannot find a way to access currently loaded store from an external `.js` file.

My application has 3 entry points for webpack, so it will create 3 bundles which share some common code. Each bundle will have different init.js file, where I provide different store.

Normally, I would simply do:

```
import Store from "@/store";
console.log(Store.state.app.someValue);
```

but I would rather do something like:

```
import Vue from "vue";
console.log(Vue.$store.state.app.someValue);
```

Because my Store will be imported not from a single file, but from one of three different files.

Is it possible to do, or do I need to combine all my stores into one object?

Comment: What is the purpose of accessing the store outside of the Vue instance, just for context?

Comment: The purpose is a gateway .js file from which I make all API requests. I keep my auth token in the store, I want to fetch it from there. Seems to be a huge overkill to import one huge central store just to get the token.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution was:

Create a single store file, and export it without any modules:

```
export default Vuex.Store({
  strict: "debug",
  plugins: [],
  // no modules
});
```

Then import it in separate entry files, and fill modules with (pseudo code):

```
import Store from "./path/to/my/store";
import modules from "./path/to/my/modules/for/this/entry/file";

modules.forEach((name, module) => Store.registerModule(name, module));
```